# Unity3D how to stop dropdown from duplicate the add?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i try to create dropdown populate with savefiles when the load button pressed the problem is when i pressed the load button more then one its load the same files again i try the indexof but still duplicate the files how i fix this pls ?!

```
     string[] getfilesname()
{
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, foldername);
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        var onlyFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        if (mylist.IndexOf(onlyFileName) == -1)
        {
            mylist.Add(onlyFileName);
        }
        Debug.Log(onlyFileName);
    }
    dropi.AddOptions(mylist);
    return filePaths;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q11HS.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IndexOf` method should take care of duplicates in the `mylist`, but you are always calling the `dropi.AddOptions(mylist);` method which will add the contents of the list again.

You should clear the `mylist` and call `dropi.ClearOptions();` at the begining of the `Load` method it this scenario is possible in your case. This way you get rid of the `if( ...IndexOf("") == -1)` too.

Comment: Thank you  for your help your answer solved my problem .